# Permuting vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, permute

I have browsed in here for answers, but unsuccessful. I have code of the following type:

```
matrix = [1, 2, 3]';

   for start = 1:3

       if start == 1
          % nothing happens
       elseif start == 2
          matrix = [matrix(2),matrix(3),matrix(1)]'
       elseif start == 3
          matrix = [matrix(3),matrix(1),matrix(2)]'
       end

   end
```

I would like to change it so that I can use it for vectors that are much longer than the matrix here, so I would like to write it in more general form. (In words, I would like to be able to start at any value in the vector, go through till the end of the vector and from the start again till the value.)

Comment: does `matrix = [matrix(start:end);matrix(1:start-1)]` work for you?

Comment: Try [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html)...

Comment: Yes, that works both I think. Thank you. (If you post it as answer I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility 1) `matrix = [matrix(start:end);matrix(1:start-1)]`

Possibility 2) `circshift` command